# ArangoDB API access via Mesos cluster on AWS

Tags: arangodb, mesos

I have an ArangoDB cluster "framwork" running on a Mesos cluster and running on AWS.  I am extremely new to Mesos.

I can access Mesos and I can access ArangoDB through the endpoint that Mesos provides:

```
http://mymesoscluster/service/arangodb3
```

I have a Java service that is not running in the Mesos cluster that I would like to use ArangoDB.  What I cannot find is how to reference ArangoDB from the API perspective.

For example, the java driver code performs a login that needs a host:

```
@Bean
public ArangoDB arangoDB() {
    ArangoDB arangoDB = new ArangoDB.Builder()
            .host("????", 8529)
            .user("root").password( "somepassword").build();
    return arangoDB;
}
```

I see some Mesos docs about API access with a token
[Authentication HTTP API Endpoint](https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.8/administration/id-and-access-mgt/oss/iam-api/)
.  I do not think that that will get me past the ArangoDB driver login.

Perhaps it is not possible with the java driver?

Comment: How do you deploy ArangoDB framework?

Comment: I installed the arangodb3 from the community catalog.

Comment: Please look below. You need to deploy access to your cluster. It is not enough to start a DC/OS cluster and install arangodb within it. You will find all the rest in the DC/OS documentation.

Comment: Right, I am looking at that.  I was just answering the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the service available from outside.
https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.11/deploying-services/expose-service/
https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.8/usage/service-discovery/marathon-lb/marathon-lb-advanced-tutorial/
If you want to access arangodb from inside, please be aware of authentication, SSL?. 
Please check back with all served services in the cluster 
`master:5050/v1/axfr`

Comment: This looks like what I need.  The arangodb framework wants to install on the private nodes and I do not know how to change the install to force them to use the public nodes.  Is it a matter of adding the "acceptedResourceRoles" to the configuration JSON and updating it?

Comment: You cannot install arangodb on public nodes. You may only expose the coordinators by following the examples above for nginx etc.

Comment: `dcos package describe --config arangodb3 > arango.json` to get the config, then I added the "label" section as the doc showed in the example, then updated the service with `cat arango.json | dcos marathon app update arangodb3`